# Creating table with longer text field by hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, hbm2ddl

I am using `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to create my tables.

Creating my column like this:

```
@Column(name = "foo", length = 8000)
private String foo;
```

This creates a table and the field : `varchar(8000)`

**What I need, is that I can make save a longer `string` than 8000 in there. Like 20000 or more.**

When changing the `length` higher than `8000`, it won't create the table.

When changing the field manually, then it says:

```
The size (20000) given to the column 'foo' exceeds the maximum allowed for 
any data type (8000).
```

Comment: I recommend you to use clob datatype for such a long text column

Comment: @RahulAgrawal and what would the type in java or annotation be for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As recommended to use Clob for such large string column

@Lob indicates that the property should be persisted in a Blob or a Clob depending on the property type: java.sql.Clob, Character[], char[] and java.lang.String will be persisted in a Clob. java.sql.Blob, Byte[], byte[] and serializable type will be persisted in a Blob.

```
@Lob
public String getFullText() {
    return fullText;
}

@Lob 
public byte[] getFullCode() {
    return fullCode;
}
```

If the property type implements java.io.Serializable and is not a basic type, and if the property is not annotated with @Lob, then the Hibernate serializable type is used.

Check example here

http://tonyyan.wordpress.com/2008/10/28/clob-and-blob-saved-through-hibernate/

Answer (score 2):

You could try using columnDefinition="LONGVARCHAR" instead of length = 8000. If using with org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2005Dialect it should be translated to varchar(max), that is able to support strings up to 2G in lengths.